# Authentication failed using Windows Credentials on ServiceNow

Tags: wmi, credentials, servicenow, discovery

I'm trying to find a host on ServiceNow, and we know that this uses WMI to do the discovery. I get the following problem in the discovery phase:

**User credentials can not be used for local connections**

I tried to execute the command directly from MID Server (192.168.1.186):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root / cimv2 -ComputerName 192.168.1.196 -Credential WORKGROUP \ administrator
```

but I get the following error:

```
Get-WmiObject: User credentials can not be used for local connections
At line: 1 char: 1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root / cimv2 -ComputerName 1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: GetWMIManagementException, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

while if I do not use -Credential, it works correctly.

This is screenshot of the Discovery Log:

[image]

Moreover, I execute MID Server using administrator user.

Answer (score 1):

Try using localhost instead of ip without credentials
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root / cimv2 -ComputerName localhost

Comment: using localhost without credentials good working, but Why I dont have use the credentials in this case?

Comment: Someone identified as "Peter" claims that "if the your App which you use for scanning runs local on the DC, it is not possible to do this by setting a Username/Password. For local actions the logged on user will be used automatically".  Someone else suggests that you cannot pass in the username/password when on the local machine. This assumes that you're logged into the local computer with admin
privileges.